# loading background "jumping" while loading

Tags: html, css

As you can see on my page, I've a loading gif. ( http://mauch-offner.com/) 
The problem is while the page is loading, the scroll-bars let the gif in the middle "jump". My thought was the overflow as hidden, but nothing changed.

the css for the gif is:

```css
#wptime-plugin-preloader {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: url(http://mo02.greendeer-projekte.de/wp-content/plugins/the-preloader/images/loading-strich.gif) no-repeat #FFFFFF 50% 50%;
  -moz-background-size: 332px 94px;
  -o-background-size: 332px 94px;
  -webkit-background-size: 332px 94px;
  background-size: 332px 94px;
  z-index: 99998;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Try forcing a scrollbar on the browser - overflow: scroll; I can't replicate your problem but when the content moves on load this usually fixes it.

Comment: it fixes the vertical "jumping", any idea how to do that for the horizontal "jumping" ?

Comment: Oh there's vertical jumping too? Sorry I can't replicate the problem because on chrome mac there's no visible scrollbars at all.

Comment: the js-script for the preloader is:`jQuery(window).load(function() { 

 jQuery('#wptime-plugin-preloader').delay(500).fadeOut("slow");
 
 setTimeout(wptime_plugin_remove_preloader, 3000);
 function wptime_plugin_remove_preloader() { 
  jQuery('#wptime-plugin-preloader').remove();
 }

});´ any idea how i can set on the body overflow:hidden before the preloader removes ? sorry i'm a beginner in js

Comment: Before jQuery('#wptime-plugin-preloader').remove(); add jQuery('body').css('overflow','hidden');

Comment: But honestly I don't understand why you would do that, it will make your site unscrollable